# Cheapest Compact/P&S sat shoots RAW

Tags: camera-recommendation, compact-cameras

What is currently the cheapest Compact  or Point & Shoot, that I can buy first-hand, that shoots RAW files?

Comment: What information brought up your own search using a search engine of your choice?

Comment: I was unable to sort by RAW shooting cameras in Google or Amazon. All it shows are compacts.

Comment: Caleb... If I got the results I wanted, why would I ask here? I have no inclination for abuse and ridicule. However, Google results in American websites, and Amazon India does not return proper results... It's showing me unrelated items everytime I search.

Comment: Will they let you test out the cameras at the local Pawn Shop? Here, their collection usually goes back at least a decade and, because of that, they're usually pretty cheap.

Comment: That is impossible to answer: we don't know where you are, and any information we give can be outdated within days

Comment: The reason you are getting less-than-helpful replies is because your question is a very bad match for this site. This site is meant to help people in general. Your question has very limited potential to be helpful, most especially over the longer term. You don't even say where you are located.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a 'Filter Site', one example of many is "[Camera Decision](http://cameradecision.com/find)":

Using the Filters: $0-500, RAW Shooting, Small Sensor Compact, and Large Sensor Compact; then clicking on the "Price" column produces:

Sigma DP1s for $248 as **the cheapest**, and Nikon P330 for $52 more as a better camera by far.

The Canon G9 XII is going to run another $28 more, skyrocketing you to $429.

Another way to view those results is that you must come up with $250 to get *something* so it's in your interests to put in a couple of hundred more to get a somewhat capable camera over investing the minimum to receive the minimum.

As mentioned that is not the only website like that, Google for "camera find comparison" to locate more similar websites.